# Android studio - Widget with configuration activity

Tags: java, android, widget

I am developing an app which has buttons with `onClickListeners`, like this:

```
final MediaPlayer szarszemetMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.szarszemet);
Button play_szarszemet = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_szarszemet);
play_szarszemet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (szarszemetMP.isPlaying()) {
            szarszemetMP.pause();
        } else {
            szarszemetMP.start();
        }
    }
});
```

I have 15 buttons now, but there will be much more.  I want to make a widget for this, where I can configure which three Buttons I want to show on my Launcher, as a 4x2 widget.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with the [Android documentation for App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)